# How to search for a substring on a LPCSTR?

Tags: c++

```
typedef _Null_terminated_ CONST CHAR *LPCSTR, *PCSTR;

// .....
LPCSTR foo = "hello world";
```

How do I search if `foo` contains `hello`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strstr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

```
LPCSTR foo = "hello world";
char * pch = strstr (foo,"hello");
```

Comment: That's' better. I couldn't get the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` to compile.

Comment: `if (strstr(foo, "hello") != NULL) {}` is it any wrong?

Comment: @user4581301 :) I was going to stop on that, but needed 30 characters for an answer

Comment: @Forth your code looks right